# NODE_PATH changes on system restart

Tags: node.js

I have an issue with node_modules for node script. In my command line i have set the node path

```
set NODE_PATH=c:\..\node_modules
```

This works when i do

```
require('socket.io');
```

But when i restart my system, require('socket.io'); will not work, it says socket.io module is not found. When i again set my NODE_PATH via command line. It will work fine. So how to set my NODE_PATH, so that it wont changes when i restart my system.

Im using Windows

Thank you......

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are restored every time you reboot. To add a variable permanently, you need to go to the System Properties:

http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/05/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/